# Error during powershell load. Unable to load database

Tags: neo4j

Using the same script as other members of my team in an admin elevated Powershell prompt, I'm trying to execute the below script and receiving error "command failed: unable to load database: NoSuchFileException

```
.\neo4j-admin load --from=C:\neo4jDumps\graphdb-20191107.dump --database=graph.db --force
```

Comment: Does the `C:\neo4jDumps\graphdb-20191107.dump` path exist on the machine you used to run the command?

Comment: In addition to @cybersam question: is it readable by the the user?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that graph.db is a folder location that didn't exist and needed to be created.